# How to find the Java executable/object in a PHP / JAVA mix?

Tags: java, php, zend-framework2

I recently got a project which seems to be a mix of PHP and Java using the zend bridge ( http://files.zend.com/help/previous-version/Zend-Server-5-IBMi/java_bridge_component.htm ) .  There is a block such {code}  $Catalog = new Java("CatalogFinder"); {code} . Can someone tell me how can I find the "CatalogFinder" file /executable ? I understand that Zend calls JAVA and proxifies the object but I need to have a look in the java file itself and I don't know how to find it . 
Disclaimer : I'm aware it's a silly question ; perhaps I should ask it on a Java forum ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for a file named "CatalogFinder.java" (source code) or "CatalogFinder.class" (compiled class).  The latter might be embedded in a ZIP or JAR file.

Comment: I was thinking about that but couldn't find it. Isn't there any "reverse" command in Java to find the file ? Is it possible to be just loaded in RAM ? I'm currently working/coding directly on the server itself due client's requirements.